# How to add tab sets into flexdashboard?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am working with `flexdashboard` and I am trying to add sub tabset into tabset . Below you can see my code:

````
---
title: "Test APPLICATION"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)

library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

library(knitr)
library(DT)
library(rpivotTable)

library(biclust)
data(BicatYeast)

data=data.frame(data(BicatYeast))

```
# Intro

Testing application


Tabset 1
=======================================================================

Row  {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Notes


### Sub tabset 1

```{r,eval=TRUE}

 rpivotTable(
             data,
             aggregatorName = "Integer Sum",
             vals="Total",
             cols = "Test",
             width="100%",
             height="400px",
             rendererName = "Table"

 )


```

### Sub tabset 2

```{r,eval=TRUE}


 rpivotTable(
             data,
             aggregatorName = "Integer Sum",
             vals="Total",
             cols = "Test",
             width="100%",
             height="400px",
             rendererName = "Table"

 )


      
```



Tabset 2
=======================================================================


Row  {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------


### Sub tabset 1

```{r,eval=TRUE}

datatable(data,
          caption = "Test",
          rownames = T,
          filter = "top",
          class = 'cell-border stripe',
          extensions='Buttons',
          options = list(
          pageLength = 50,
          dom = 'Blfrtip',
          buttons=c('copy','csv','excel','pdf','print'),
          lengthMenu = list(c(10,25,50,-1),c(10,25,50,"All"))

          ))
         
```

### Sub tabset 2

```{r,eval=TRUE}

datatable(data,
          caption = "Test",
          rownames = T,
          filter = "top",
          class = 'cell-border stripe',
          extensions='Buttons',
          options = list(
          pageLength = 50,
          dom = 'Blfrtip',
          buttons=c('copy','csv','excel','pdf','print'),
          lengthMenu = list(c(10,25,50,-1),c(10,25,50,"All"))

          ))

      
```
````

[image]

Now, I want to put additional tab sets under Sub tabset 1. Can anybody help me on how to solve this problem and add additional tab sets (two or three)?